# Ошибка при использовании #include <iostream> вместо #include <stdafx.h>

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В visual studio C++, при создании нового проекта, вместо `#include <iostream>` (как в примерах) стоит `#include <stdafx.h>`.
Если его заменить на `#include <iostream>`, то получается ошибка компиляции.

Можно это как-то изменить?

Comment: Что? Убрать запятую? подведите курсор, нажмите `Delete`...

Comment: #include<stdafx.h>, А не запятую. Когда изменяю её и компилирую проект пишет ошибку в Visual studio

Comment: 1) приведите код вызывающий ошибку (текстом) 2) приведите ошибку (текстом)

Comment: Не понимаю - кто вам мешает написать в программе тот текст, который вам нужен? А заодно, если не хотите stdafx, указывать, что предкомпилированный заголовок проекту не нужен...

Answer (score 4):

Это особенность Visual Studio, которая может ускорять сборку проекта. Начинающих только сбивает с толку. Рекомендую её просто отключить, только и всего. Тогда все будет работать как по учебнику.

Для этого зайдите в свойства проекта (правая кнопка по проекту в solution explorer, properties) и в Precompiled Headers отключите их как показано на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятна характеристика "нестандартная". А разве есть какие-то стандарты на инфраструктуру среды компиляции?

Comment: @AnT Все верно, но разве мы не должны ожидать, что корректный с точки зрения стандарта код должен собираться без ошибок?

Comment: Должны. За исключением тез случаев, когда внешние установки компиляции специально предотвращают такую сборку. Вас же не удивит, что простое внешнее `-Dfor=mew`, "сломает" большое количество совершенно стандартного С++ кода? Тогда и во многом аналогичные внешние установки, запрашивающие специальную обработку для `stdafx.h`, не должны удивлять.

Comment: @AnT Вы правы, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio использует `#include <stdafx.h>` для реализации предкомпилированных заголовков — то есть, для ускорения компиляции. `#include <stdafx.h>` должно быть первой существенной строкой файла (то есть, непустой и не комментарием).

Если вам нужно указать `#include <iostream>`, укажите его следующей строкой.

---

Я бы не рекомендовал отказываться от `#include <stdafx.h>` и предкомпилированных заголовков. Правильное использование предкомпилированных заголовков улучшает время компиляции, особенно в больших проектах.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70733/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----include-iostream-).